# PHP OOP Factory pattern and Open/Closed principle

Tags: php, oop, factory-pattern, solid-principles

I would like to implements PHP notifications system with PHP OOP. I have many notifications type and each notification will do custom work and checks user settings before showing notification to users. I add Notification abstract class to fix Notification behaviour for all notifications types.

```
abstract class Notification {     
    private $notificationType;
    
    public function __construct(int $type) {
      $this->notificationType=$type;
    }

    //put your code here
    public abstract function notify(array $user_settings);
}
```

Then I extend parent Notification class with childrens classes like this:

```
    class AddRequestNotifiation extends Notification{
        //put your code here
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(1);
        }
        public function notify(array $user_settings) {
            echo "custom ad request work here";
        }
    }

//----
class LikesNotification extends Notification{
    //put your code here
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(2);
    }
    public function notify(array $user_settings) {
        echo "custom likes  work here";
    }
}
```

Now I would like to implements Factory pattern.

```
class NotificationFactory {
    //put your code here    
    public static function buildNotification(int $type){
        if($type==1){
            return new AddRequestNotifiation();
        }else if($type==2){
            return new LikesNotification();
        }else{
           throw new Exception("not implemented");
        }
    }
}
```

Then in index.html

```
$notification= NotificationFactory::buildNotification(1);
$notification->notify([]);
```

I know that Factory is bad because it d'ont respect O/C principle and i need to modify it to add new Notification type so I choose another approche like below :

```
class NotificationFactory {
    //put your code here    
    private $notifications=array();
    
    public function addNotificationType(int $type, Notification  $n){
        if(!array_key_exists($type,$this->notifications)){
          $this->notifications[$type]=$n;  
        }
    }
    
    public function buildNotification(int $type):Notification{
        if(!array_key_exists($type,$this->notifications)){
            throw new Exception("Not Implemented");
        }else{
            return $this->notifications[$type];
        } 
    }
}
```

Then I populated factory with all notifications types.

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
       include $class .".php";
    });

    // initialisation
    $notification_factory= new NotificationFactory();
    $notification_factory->addNotificationType(1, new AddRequestNotifiation());
    $notification_factory->addNotificationType(2, new LikesNotification());
    // adding new custom notification
    $notification_factory->addNotificationType(12, new CustomNotification());
    
    /// then when Notification arrive
    $notification = $notification_factory->buildNotification(2);
    $notification->notify([]);
```

With this approche O/C principle is respected but there is big probleme with memory and ressource using befaore I must instanciate all notifications type even when I d'ont use them . what is the optimised solution for this.

Comment: do you mean, OOP ?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry OOP (POO in frensh).

Comment: If the code works and you just want someone to review it and come with suggestions, it should rather be posted over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: And questions about design principles may be more appropriate for [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: It doesn't look like major overhead there. Why do you need to initialize them all up-front though? Also, your "factory" looks like it's a _warehouse_ for objects already instantiated? For ease of maintenance, use constants instead of magic numbers. Even class constants, e.g. `LikesNotification::ID`. Then you could also pass in e.g. 'LikesNotification' and have it instantiated and the ID assigned _inside your factory warehouse rig_.) Other than that, yes, OT for SO. :(

Comment: Ok for replacing magic numbers by constants. but I'm forced to instantiate all notifications subclass before calling factory to link each notification type to notification object to avoid using switch inside factory and then avoid O/C principle broken. and also to add any new custom notification to factory without editing code. Can you show me implemntation code with constant class to see if this will be better in term of performance and overhead ???

Answer (score -1):

After some investigations I found another pattern witch is more appropriate to my requirement, that respect O/C principle and not use much memory ressources. This Pattern is not much used and called Proxy.
Below haw I implemented it:

```
    interface NotificationInterface {
        //put your code here
        public function notify();
    }

class LikesNotification implements NotificationInterface{
    //put your code here
    public function notify() {
        echo "Likes Notification content".PHP_EOL;
    }    
}

class AddRequestNotification implements NotificationInterface{
    //put your code here
    public function notify() {
        echo "Add Request Notification Content" .PHP_EOL;
    }    
}
```

Then I used a Notification proxy class. for this I used the magic php method __call() witch fire by default if an object instance of class is called with a method that is not implemented in class.

```
class NotificationProxy {    
    //put your code here
    protected $instance;
    
    public function __construct($type) {
       $class=$type."Notification";
       $this->instance=new $class();
    }
    
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array([$this->instance,$name],$arguments);
    }
}
```

Then in index.php I called only the appropriate Notification class by json received type:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    include $class .".php";
});

/** we get incoming Notification JSON { 'type':'Likes'} **/
$notification_Proxy=new NotificationProxy("Likes");
$notification_Proxy->notify();

/** if incoming Notification JSON has type { 'type':'AddRequest'} **/
$notification_Proxy=new NotificationProxy("AddRequest");
$notification_Proxy->notify();
```

That is all I hope that this solution will be helpfull to someone else.